# Java Pattern matcher not matching for HTTP response code

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I trying to use java pattern matching to extract the http response code from a single line in the http response header, but for some reason it is not matching. 
I dont suppose anyone could point out where i am going wrong..?

This is my code:`

```
private static String getSubString(String regex, String data ) {
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
          if(matcher.matches()) {
              return matcher.group(1);
          }
          return null;
      }`
```

And this is my test input to the method:

```
data = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request";
regex = "([0-9][0-9][0-9])";
```

for some reason matcher.matches() is returning false.

Thanks heaps for any help anyone can provide
Corey

Comment: Just a question; Wouldnt it be better to use the actual response object, if available? Then you would not have to do such parsing/patterng matching.

Comment: You need to use `matcher.find()`. `matches`  is for matching the whole string.Which in your case it is false.